# Using cd command in shell script with a variable containing a path is not working in CentOS virtualbox environment with Windows 10 host

Tags: shell, centos, windows-10, virtualbox

**Background:**

I am coming across an issue that none of my colleagues are experiencing with there Linux machines.  I have a Windows 10 machine and I have found a work-around by hard-coding the path in the shell script, but that is not desired, of course.

The following is from a shell script for Jetty to run within an CentOS virtualbox hosted on Windows 10.  If you are familiar with Jetty the line in particular is located on line #250 of jetty.sh.

**Problem:**

In shell script the `cd` command will not work with a variable:

```
cd "$JETTY_BASE"
```

**Error:**

```
: No such file or directory: cd: /opt/jetty
```

**Facts:**

1. The directory exists.
2. The variable holds the correct path.
3. When attempting the following command with a hard-coded path, the shell script works:

   `cd /opt/jetty`

**Question:**

- Why will the variable not work in my case, when it works for everyone else?
- How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

It turns out that in Jetty.sh, there is a config file that set the $JETTY_BASE, $JETTY_HOME variables.  The config file had line endings for Windows rather than for Unix.  After change the config file to use Unix, I copied the file into the CentOS virtualbox and the script performed correctly.

**Summary:**

If Windows is your host machine for Linux-based virtual machines, make sure the files copied from Windows to the Linux-based virtual machine is using Unix-based line endings.